# How can I improve VS 2013 markup editor performance?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

The performance of the markup editor in VS 2013 is horrible. Each time I press a key I have to wait a little bit to see the results.

Is there any way to improve the performance, to make it work faster, maybe disable intellisense or code analysis for markup?

How do You handle this issue, because I can't work right now.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Have you tried Resharper? http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Yes, it improves development process but doesnt or even has negative impact on VS user experience performance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in this case the problem was with the balance power consumption laptop setting which changed after system reinstallation. After switching to high performance reaction speed in vs is acceptable, but still maybe You have any hints on improveing it even more ?